# Cannot sync photos from photos app to iphone using iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos

When I navigate to photos from my phone settings in iTunes, I am not able to select the photos.app from the "copy photos from" dropdown.

My Photo Library exist in the Pictures directory and it is set as a system photos library.
My photo library is not corrupt. The access level is not restricted.

I have my iCloud photos option disabled.
I am running Mojave 10.14.6

How do I sync my photos app library to my iPhone through iTunes?

[image: itunes photo]

Comment: **Tip**: When you can't sync, you can use the `Image Capture` app to manually copy photos and videos from any iDevice. Just connect your iDevice and open the app.

Answer (score 1):

What I did to solve this problem is to reinstall my OS. I don't need to wipe my hard drive clean. The problem could be due to some corruption in the system files.